# HTML5 - how to run videos from CLIENT MACHINE?

Tags: asp.net, html, html5-video

I'm not able to run videos from CLIENT MACHINE using HTML5. See the following syntax.

```
<div>
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="file://D:/Videos/bigbuckbunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

Somebody can help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For security reasons, this is unlikely to be possible.

Comment: It should work if you have the videos in the same folder as the HTML file and use relative paths, but don't expect a `file:///` path to work from a page loaded through `http://`

Answer (score 1):

I am very curious as to why you'll want to do this. This will never work, because you can't be sure that your client has the video on his/her harddrive. You also dont want to access your clients local machine, for security reasons.

If you would want all clients to see the same video, you should instead upload the video to a server and link to that. You could, for example, upload the video to your webhotel. Like this:

```
'http://yourwebsite.com/videos/bigbuckbunny.mp4'
```

Hope my answer was somewhat helpful.

Comment: Actually I want to play that video repeatedly that's why I was thinking it from client side.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean? It's not a plausible solution to do it the way your propose. Videos should always be serverside, as you cannot be sure that is exists on your clients computer, among many other reasons.